# GitLab CI/CD Pipeline Variable Validation like Jenkins?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I utilize the GitLab pipeline for automation testing, where I rely on a set of parameters (variables) for input into the test automation pipeline. The challenge lies in the fact that if a user inputs an incorrect value for any parameter, the job proceeds to execution and only fails some time later, and it would still consume resources and needs a runner for executing that stage.

Is there a way to implement parameter validation before initiating the Gitlab pipeline manually? We had something similar from Jenkins from a "Validating String Parameter Plugin".

I tried adding a stage: .pre but that would still consume resources and take a couple of minutes.

Comment: Why would `.pre` take a couple of minutes? If you're validating inputs, it should be almost immediate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rules` and add a condition to your variable. The job will only run if the condition is met.

```yaml
job:
  script: // do something
  rules:
    - if: $MY_VAR == "string value"
```

You have a panel of examples in [the doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html).